# Macro Substitution/Expansion in Environment Names

Tags: macros, environments, tex-core, expansion, substitution

I've noticed that you can use macros for substitution into environment names:

```
\def\itmz{itemize}
\begin\itmz
\item Item the first
\item Item the second
\end\itmz             % works
```

It also works with `\newcommand` in place of `\def`.

However, this doesn't work (`\end\itmz` replaced by `\end{itemize}`),

```
\def\itmz{itemize}
\begin\itmz
\item Item the first
\item Item the second
\end{itemize}         % doesn't work
```

and I get the following somewhat cryptic error message:

```
! Latex Error: \begin{itemize} (...) ended by \end{itemize}
```

What is the difference here, behind the scenes, for the `tex` compiler?

BTW: I'm not asking because I want to save keystrokes in typing `itemize`; I'm trying to understand how `tex`'s macro substitution/expansion model works.

Comment: Funny error message, isn't it? I also know how to make LaTeX stop with “Missing `\begin{document}`” at `\begin{document}`. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a TeX level, `\begin` takes one argument (`<name>`), which is then used to look for a macro which is the *expansion* of `<name>` to 'characters'. So here, we are looking for `\itemize`. That exists, so we start a list. The `<name>` is also saved *as given*: that's going to be important. (The data is saved in `\@currenvir`.)

At the end of the environment, `\end` also grabs one argument. It then does a check that the argument it's grabbed matches the current environment name. However, there is no expansion done: we are doing the same as

```
\def\name{itemize}
\def\tempa{\name}
\def\tempb{itemize}
\ifx\tempa\tempb
  % TRUE
\else
  % FALSE
\fi
```

As you'll find if you run the example, that's FALSE: the definitions are not the same (although they expand to the same thing).

You get an 'interesting' message as printing the message *does* do expansion. So what you see is what you probably thought you were doing!

One could argue that the LaTeX kernel could `\edef` (exhaustively expand) the name of the environment at both ends, in which case the issue would vanish. However, the formal LaTeX doesn't support giving environment names as macros: that's a technical detail. (It would be valid to detokenize the arguments and use them as-is, for example.)